# SQL adding same column but with different values

Tags: sql, oracle

PROBLEM TO SOLVE: how can I add second column name for index '168? I have tried some methods but its returns back the column with names of index from end_station_id.

QUERY

```
SELECT t.start_station_id, t.end_station_id, si.name 
FROM trips t
INNER JOIN stations_info si ON si.station_id = t.end_station_id 
WHERE t.start_station_id IN (SELECT station_id FROM stations_info
                             WHERE name = 'ROUT 61';
```

RETURNS

```
START_STATION_ID END_STATION_ID NAME                                                                                                                            

             168            195 Bay Pl at Vernon St                                                                                                             
             168            157 65th St at Hollis St                                                                                                            
             168            274 Oregon St at Adeline St                                                                                                         
             168            241 Ashby BART Station                                                                                                              
             168            252 Channing Way at Shattuck Ave
```

TABLE ONE includes columns:

```
STATION_ID
NAME
SHORT_NAME
REGION_ID
RENTAL_METHODS
CAPACITY
EXTERNAL_ID
RENTAL_URL
EIGHTD_HAS_KEY_DISPENSER
HAS_KIOSK
STATION_GEOM
```

TABLE TWO includes columns:

```
TRIP_ID
START_DATE
START_STATION_ID
END_DATE
END_STATION_ID
BIKE_NUMBER
ZIP_CODE
SUBSCRIBER_TYPE
C_SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE
MEMBER_BIRTH_YEAR
MEMBER_GENDER
BIKE_SHARE_FOR_ALL_TRIP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the name for both the start and end stations.  If so:

```
SELECT t.start_station_id, t.end_station_id,
       sis.name as start_station_name,
       sie.name as end_station_name
FROM trips t INNER JOIN
     stations_info sie
     ON sie.station_id = t.end_station_id INNER JOIN
     stations_info sis
     ON sis.station_id = t.start_station_id
WHERE t.start_station_id IN (SELECT si.station_id
                             FROM stations_info
                             WHERE si.name = 'ROUT 61'
                            );
```

Actually, you can simplify the `WHERE` clause to:

```
SELECT t.start_station_id, t.end_station_id,
       sis.name, sie.name 
FROM trips t INNER JOIN
     stations_info sie
     ON sie.station_id = t.end_station_id INNER JOIN
     stations_info sis
     ON sis.station_id = t.start_station_id
WHERE sis.name = 'ROUT 61';
```